# how do i put a splatter image in between mdx content like a mdx blog?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, css-position, mdxjs

i have an mdx blog that renders a blog post.

#### pages/index.tsx

```
<main className="flex min-h-screen dark:bg-black">
                <div className="wrapper mb-24 gap-8 px-8 lg:grid lg:grid-cols-[1fr,70px,min(70ch,calc(100%-64px)),70px,1fr]">
                    <div className="mdx-wrapper prose relative col-[2/5] max-w-full dark:prose-light lg:grid lg:grid-cols-[70px_1fr_70px]">
                        <MDXLayoutRenderer mdxSource={props.code as never} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
```

the `MDXLayoutRenderer` is where the mdx is inserted in the page.

#### index.mdx

```
this is a title

import { Splatter } from '../../components/Splatter.tsx'

this is a block

some giberrish

some giberrish

some giberrish

some giberrish

<Splatter />

yet another block

some giberrish

some giberrish

some giberrish

some giberrish
```

#### components/Splatter.tsx

```
export const Splatter = () => (
    <div className="relative inset-0 h-64 w-64 bg-[url('/splatter.jpg')]">
    </div>
)
```

#### public/splatter.jpg

[image: splatter]

---

for some reason, the splatter either overlaps the text in `index.mdx` or it acts like a `div`, i.e, it pushes down the `yet another block`

i want the splatter to be in the background like a background image.

i'm not sure how to do it? i did try using an `img` but it didn't give the desired result.

my current method of `bg-[url('/splatter.jpg')]` is just a background image in tailwind. it doesn't work either.

i tried using z-index & different positions absolute & relative but it doesn't go in the background.

what's the fix to this?

Comment: you want this to be as background for some section  ?

Comment: i want it in the middle of mdx. one time in the left, one time in the right. kinda like justjavascript(dot)com has below. but in mdx.its easy in html but mdx makes it a bit difficult.

Comment: in JJS, they have used absolute, z-index, h-37%, b-0 also their image is transparent bg with empty space in between, main content is higher z-index, you gotta do similar or may be you can try with `:before` and `:after`. To use just like them you need to update your image

Comment: already tried that but it isnt getting my image in the background for some reason. hence, i asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with two images, position them `absolute` with `left` and `right` with parent position `relative` and negative `z-index`.

Something like this:

```
export const Splatter = () => (
  <div className="relative -z-10">
    <div className="absolute bg-cover left-[100%] h-96 w-[500px] bg-[url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0ik2.jpg')]"></div>
    <div className="absolute bg-cover right-[100%] h-96 w-[500px] bg-[url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0ik2.jpg')]"></div>
  </div>
);
```

Play around with `height` and `width` to get what suits you. For smaller screen I think you should hide this.

Here is the [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/next-js-mdx-js-forked-yxbzun?file=%2Fcomponents%2FSplatter.jsx%3A7%2C1).

Comment: thank you madan, your demo works. i had to change a bit about my css to get it working but i used your ideas to get it done. been too long since i did any css so forgetting the basics.